# Get the alt text of the image in a array

Tags: php, functions, post-thumbnails

I have a php code. That put the thumbs on the screen. I have this:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
<div class="image">
    <?php
        $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' )
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="186" height="137" alt="">
    <?php //the_post_thumbnail('default_product_img'); ?>
</div><!-- /image -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

The code is good. The images are showing and that is good. But now i have a problem. I can not putt the alt text in the image.

How can i add the alt text of the image, in the alt tag of the image?

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

This simply do the same work and also output the `alt` value:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
<div class="image"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(186, 137) ); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

See [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

Comment: Thank you. This is working. How can i remove the attachment-186x137 wp-post-image classes of the image?

Comment: `<?php echo str_replace(' wp-post-image', '', get_the_post_thumbnail( null, array(186, 137), array('class'=>'') ) ); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the function [wp_get_attachment_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)

```
<?php 
if (has_post_thumbnail()) : 

 $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
 $attr_args = array(
    'class' => 'overriden-class',
    'alt'   => 'override-if-required'
 );
 $size = array(186,137);
 echo '<div class="image">';
 echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id,$size,$icon=false,$attr_args);
 echo '</div>';
endif;


?>
```

If you need the original `alt tag` remove the alt key from the `$attr_args` array